# Mixing repellant with non-repellant termiticide - does that actually work?

Tags: pest-control

So I had an exterminator that wanted to mix Demon Max and Termidor, which seems like a repellent and non-repellent termiticide.

Is that counter-productive since the repellent will just chase termites away from the Termidor?

What am I missing here?

The worst thing is I asked him not to do that and repeated the request 5 times to which he agreed every time - but then I caught him mixing the two in my ring camera.

Comment: it appears that you cannot trust that person ... do not leave them in your house without supervision

Comment: That may be like asking a mechanic not to use assembly lube when rebuilding a motor. The repellent helps get rid of swarms that have not taken up residence yet but are shopping for a new place to hangout. The insecticide is to kill the ones that have moved in. If they offer a guarantee they are probably following what they normally do. What you are missing is the chemical license or training they normally require to do the job. I have tried and failed in the past with these wood chewing insects but the pros have taken care of them why second guess what they do for a living?

Comment: I'd guess that the professional nodded and grunted to get you to go away so he could do his job. You _might_ get a better response asking him next time he's there about how/why this works since it seems to you (a non-expert) to be counterintuitive. Appeal to his knowledge to educate you instead of insulting him, and I'm sure he'd be happy to explain exactly why he's doing what he's doing.

Comment: Yeah already did that, since other expert pest control people wouldn't recommend it.  He didn't give a logical explanation.  He said that it's stronger that way and it's always worked.